# i need to tag the docker image with commit has in docker build task but not complete hash only first 7 characters of hash in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

need to tag image with first 7 characters of commit has value in azure build pipeline. but unable to get it , missing syntax issue somewhere.

tried as below

```
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Write your commands here

        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag] $(build.sourceversion) | cut -c-7)"
        echo "$dockertag"
```

dockertag is used as tag in docker build task in pipeline.

it does not output anything . am i missing anything or do we have any alternative way of doing it.

Comment: i friend, any update for this issue? Please consider [accepting it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) If my answer below helps to resolve this issue. Also feel free to let me know if you need any further assistance. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `##vso[task.setvariable` way to set variable in script, the variable's value should work for subsequent tasks but not **current** task. Try something like this:

```
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your commands here
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(Build.SourceVersion)|cut -c-7"
          echo $(Build.SourceVersion)
          echo done

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo $(Build.SourceVersion)
          echo $(dockertag)
          echo '**********'
          echo $dockertag
          echo '**********'
```

**Result:**

[image]

So if your first bash task works well to set the `dockertag` variable, your following steps can use the variable via format `$(dockertag)`, not `$dockertag`.

Also, it should be `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(Build.SourceVersion)|cut -c-7"`.